# R: Error in calculating the average of a variable at different time intervals for many factors using for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, time, average

I have a data frame in which a variable(var1) is expressed over time in seconds. I want to calculate the mean of var1 for each sample at different time intervals (10 seconds interval until 500 seconds).
the dataframe looks like this:

```
sample   time      var1 
S1        1         3.5
S1        2         6.3
S1        3         7.8
S1        4         20.5
S1        …         ...
S1        530       4.5
S2        1         6.7
S2        2         20.3
S2        3         5.4
S2        …         ...
S2        710       70.3
...
```

The data frame that I want to obtain looks like this

```
Sample     var1_mean10:20sec    var1_mean20:30sec  ....  var1_mean490:500sec  
S1
S2
..
```

So I wrote this code:

```
setwd("…")
A <- read_excel("dati.xlsx")
for (cat in unique(A$sample))
{
 A.s <- subset(A, A$sample == cat)
 cuts <- cut (A.s$time, breaks=seq.int(from = 0, to = 500, by = 10))
 d <- by (A.s$var1, cuts, mean)
 Y<-data.frame(d)
 j <- t(Y)
 write.csv(Y, file = paste(cat, "var1", sep = "_"))
}
```

But when I run it I get Error message: `Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : cannot coerce class ""by"" to a data.frame`

The plan is to eventually merge all the different csv.

Comment: Please dput(yourdata[1:10, ]). This helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly you are trying to average your data in 10 second interval. I would like to propose an alternative approach using the function `aggregate` to compute the mean across the 10 seconds interval. The 10 seconds interval would be created through a fictitious 'time' array used to group your 10 seconds interval and then averaging.

```
    # try to create some data similar to yours
    A <- data.frame(sample = c(rep('A1', 530), rep('A2', 710)), 
              time = c(1 : 530, 1:710), var1 = runif(530+710))
    A$times <- ceiling(A$time / 10)
    Y <- aggregate(var1 ~ sample + times, data = A, FUN = mean)
```

Then you could export `tmp` straightaway.
HTH

Comment: The thing is that I have many samples and it was not convenient to write this for all of them.

Comment: I might not get your problem, but the line I provided you with would give you an average for all samples in bins of 10 seconds. No need to loop. Anyway, I see you solved it yourself, so congratulations.

Answer (score 0):

Solved :

```
A <- read_excel("data.xlsx")
n <- subset(A, time <= 500)
d<-data.frame(sample= n$sample, time= n$time, ms=n$var1)
storage.data<-data.frame(matrix(nrow = n, ncol = n))
for(cat in unique(d$sample)){
  g <- subset(d, d$sample == cat)
  cuts <- cut (g$time, breaks=seq.int(from = 0, to = 500, by = 10))
  p <- by (g$ms, cuts, mean)
  storage.data[cat] = p}

View(storage.data)
storage.data_t <- t(storage.data)
View(storage.data_t)
write.csv(storage.data_t, file = "filename.csv")
```